# Make submit button close dialog and return focus to spreadsheet google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

When I click submit focus returns to spreadsheet and data get loaded, but dialog box does not get closed. I used `google.script.host.close()`, but that won't pass focus back to spreadsheet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<form >
  Select Client:
  <div>
  <select id="optionList" name="client">   
  </select>
  </div> 
   Select Action:
  <div>
  <select id="actionList" name="action">   
  </select>
  </div> 
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="username"> <br />
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="password"> <br />
  <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="google.script.run.callNumbers(this.parentNode);google.script.host.editor.focus();" />
</form>
  </body>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
    $(function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
            .getClients();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildActionList)
            .getActions();
    });

    function buildOptionList(clients) {
        var list = $('#optionList');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            list.append(new Option(clients[i]));
        }
    }

     function buildActionList(actions) {
        var list = $('#actionList');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
            list.append(new Option(actions[i]));
        }
    }
</script>


</html>
```

```
    function html(){
       var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('load');
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Input API Creddentials');
    }
```

I want to get focus back to Spreadsheet after closing dialog. I have tried using google html template instead dialog within sandbox mode, but that didn't work.

When I use `google.script.host.editor.focus()` and `google.script.host.close()` together it didn't send focus back to sheet.

Comment: `When I use google.script.host.editor.focus() and google.script.host.close() together`. Show how you used them together and if there are any errors on the console.

Comment: <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="google.script.run.callNumbers(this.parentNode);google.script.host.close();google.script.host.editor.focus();" /> 

No errors on console. Dialog get closed. No data loaded on spreadsheet

Comment: How about `focus()` first and `close()` next?

Comment: tried. Didn't work

Comment: `Dialog get closed. No data loaded on spreadsheet` But focus gets to the spreadsheet right?

Comment: I'm evaluating focus from data loading. Since no data loaded I assumed focus also not returned since data retrieval is already confirmed. If there's any other way to evaluate focus let me know.

Comment: `I'm evaluating focus from data loading` I'm sorry, but what do you mean by data loading? You mean callNumbers  function on the server side ran? Are you saying that if you use `close()`, `callNumbers()` doesn't run?

Comment: I meant callNumbers() ran and data generated, but didn't visualize on spreadsheet since it didn't get focus back on it.

Comment: If dialog gets closed, focus is automatically on the spreadsheet. Right? What makes you think that the spreadsheet doesn't show it?

Comment: Go through my answer, then you'll get what I meant. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use success handler to close my dialog after calling function and that worked.

```
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).callNumbers(this.parentNode);google.script.host.editor.focus();" />
```

This will close dialog window and return focus on spread sheet.